# PHP move uploaded file

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an upload script with html forms and PHP, I've seen a lot of people using `move_uploaded_file` and I can't figure out what it does, I looked around and all other websites are too complex for me. Can someone "dumb" it down a bit for me?

An example of what i saw:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
```

Also can someone explain `$_FILES` to me aswell?

Comment: It moves the file from a temp folder to the location you specify.

Comment: What do you mean temp folder? is that where the files are stored during POST or what?

Comment: The official PHP docs at http://php.net are the place to read about these features http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Michael, i looked there but didn't understand it.

Comment: `$_FILES` is one of [PHP's superglobal arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) which is always available in all scopes.  Files posted from multipart/form-data forms populate information about themselves in `$_FILES`.

Comment: Is a file stored in a temporary location when you press "submit" using post? if that's true it makes everything a whole lot easier

Comment: Yes that is true, it is uploaded to a temp location on server when you upload it

Comment: Yes - when submitting the file, it is stored in a temporary place pointed to by the `tmp_name` key in `$_FILES`.

Comment: Oh thanks! Its great how quickly you get a response on this site! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES is a superglobal, much like $_GET or $_POST, that stores the information about the uploaded file.

If the name of your upload input form element is 'myfile' then, after uploading you will have an assiciative array $_FILES['myfile'] storing all the data about the uploaded file. To learn about it, just var_dump() it:

```
var_dump($_FILES['myfile']);
```

All the uploaded files are usually first uploaded to the /tmp directory (or whatever directory is set for this purpose in the php.ini file). After doing some sanity checks about the file (like testing for the right mime type), you will want to move the file to it's final destination. That's what the move_uploaded_file() function is intendedn for.

In this case $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] is the temporary file path of the uploaded file and $uploadfile should store the final path of the file.

Answer (score 2):

> move_uploaded_file — Moves an uploaded file to a new location
>
> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
> a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
> upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
> filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
> anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
> user, or even to other users on the same system.

Which part of that [Manual](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) you need help with?

Comment: Sorry, i can't accept this for 6 minutes, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) from the PHP Manual:

> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) from the PHP Manual:

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

---

You can use it like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], './uploads/'.$_FILES['picture']['name']))
    echo 'File successfully uploaded';
else
    echo 'File could not be uploaded';
```

---

`$_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']`:

> The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

`$_FILES['picture']['name']`:

> The original name of the file on the client machine.

For more information check out [POST Method Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)